Given two points on the Poincaré disk model, what is the formula for a hyperbolic line passing through the two points?
I'm trying to code a Scratch project where you can place two (or more) points in a Poincaré disk to create hyperbolic lines. So far, the engine is going pretty well, but the actual line in between the two points is unsuccessful.
More context:
Hyperbolic lines are part of another circle aside from the disk, of which the intersections of this circle and the disk itself are perpendicular.
$A=(x_1,y_1)$, $B=(x_2,y_2)$, and the disk has a radius of 100.
Originally, I was just looking to find the circle's center and trigonometric equation where the intersections were at right angles, but then I'd stumble into a problem, with lines that are closer to straight lines, the circle is huge, which meant the circle's center extended outside the parameters of Scratch's Cartesian plane (the center's x and y coordinates must be in these parameters, $-240\le x\le240$, $-180\le y\le180$), even worse, when $A$ and $B$ are part of the diameter, the circle is infinitely huge.
So help me find an equation for the circle where it doesn't involve using parts of the circle such as the radius or center, or else prove this is impossible, thank you.

It is far easier in the upper half-plane model. You can combine it with a liner fractional transformation between the upper half plane and the disk.

That actually sounds a lot easier, thank you, I'll try this first.
